# Specified text file not found for File I/O in Eclipse

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to do a file I/O in eclipse. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TextDB {
    public static final String SEPARATOR = "|";

    // an example of reading
    public static ArrayList readProfessors(String filename) throws IOException {
        // read String from text file
        ArrayList stringArray = (ArrayList) read(filename);
        ArrayList alr = new ArrayList();// to store Professors data

        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.size(); i++) {
            String st = (String) stringArray.get(i);
            // get individual 'fields' of the string separated by SEPARATOR
            StringTokenizer star = new StringTokenizer(st, SEPARATOR);        // pass in the string to the string tokenizer using delimiter ","

            String name = star.nextToken().trim();        // first token
            String email = star.nextToken().trim();        // second token
            int contact = Integer.parseInt(star.nextToken().trim()); // third token
            // create Professor object from file data
            Professor prof = new Professor(name, email, contact);
            // add to Professors list
            alr.add(prof);
        }
        return alr;
    }

    // an example of saving
    public static void saveProfessors(String filename, List al) throws IOException {
        List alw = new ArrayList();// to store Professors data

        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            Professor prof = (Professor) al.get(i);
            StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
            st.append(prof.getName().trim());
            st.append(SEPARATOR);
            st.append(prof.getEmail().trim());
            st.append(SEPARATOR);
            st.append(prof.getContact());
            alw.add(st.toString());
        }
        write(filename, alw);
    }

    /**
     * Write fixed content to the given file.
     */
    public static void write(String fileName, List data) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                out.println((String) data.get(i));
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the contents of the given file.
     */
    public static List read(String fileName) throws IOException {
        List data = new ArrayList();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        try {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                data.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] aArgs) {
        TextDB txtDB = new TextDB();
        String filename = "professor.txt";
        try {
            // read file containing Professor records.
            ArrayList al = TextDB.readProfessors(filename);
            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                Professor prof = (Professor) al.get(i);
                System.out.println("Name " + prof.getName());
                System.out.println("Contact " + prof.getContact());
            }
            Professor p1 = new Professor("Joseph", "jos@ntu.edu.sg", 67909999);
            // al is an array list containing Professor objs
            al.add(p1);
            // write Professor record/s to file.
            TextDB.saveProfessors(filename, al);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException > " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And my Professor class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Professor implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private int contact;

    public Professor(String n, String e, int c) {
        name = n;
        email = e;
        contact = c;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Professor) {
            Professor p = (Professor) o;
            return (getName().equals(p.getName()));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, when I run it, the compiler told the the specified file "professor.txt" is not found. I thought the compiler will create the text file automatically based on these code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your program tries to read from that file and doesn't find it. Writing to the would happens _after_ that error.

Comment: No it won't, nowhere in your code are you checking if the file `exists()` , and if it doesn't exist, `createNewFile()` . see. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html . Also note that the compiler only compiles your application, and the JVM runs your application .

Comment: But I ran it for the first time, it works and created the text file. After that, I deleted the text file and it won't create again

Comment: in your main you are firstly reading the file and  then write it: if the file doesn't exist it will throw you the exception. Probably, the first time you ran it, the file was present (maybe you have write the code to write the file first and then you have launch it)

Comment: It does not work even though I added if (!exist) {
   f = new File(fileName);
   f.createNewFile();
  } Any ideas?

Comment: doesn't work it's too vague... post your exception

Answer (score 0):

In your main you are firstly reading the file and then write it: if the file doesn't exist it will throw you the exception. Probably, the first time you ran it, the file was present (maybe you have write the code to write the file first and then you have launch it).

so, two solutions...

First: change the order of your main.

```
public static void main(String[] aArgs) {
    TextDB txtDB = new TextDB();
    String filename = "professor.txt";
    try {
        Professor p1 = new Professor("Joseph", "jos@ntu.edu.sg", 67909999);
        // al is an array list containing Professor objs
        al.add(p1);
        // write Professor record/s to file.
        TextDB.saveProfessors(filename, al);

        // read file containing Professor records.
        ArrayList al = TextDB.readProfessors(filename);
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            Professor prof = (Professor) al.get(i);
            System.out.println("Name " + prof.getName());
            System.out.println("Contact " + prof.getContact());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException > " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Second: check if the file exist or not and then skip the read of it if it doesn't

```
public static void main(String[] aArgs) {
    TextDB txtDB = new TextDB();
    String filename = "professor.txt";
    try {
        //check if the file exist
        File oFile = new File(filename);
        if(oFile.exist()) {
            // read file containing Professor records.
            ArrayList al = TextDB.readProfessors(filename);
            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                Professor prof = (Professor) al.get(i);
                System.out.println("Name " + prof.getName());
                System.out.println("Contact " + prof.getContact());
            }
        }

        Professor p1 = new Professor("Joseph", "jos@ntu.edu.sg", 67909999);
        // al is an array list containing Professor objs
        al.add(p1);
        // write Professor record/s to file.
        TextDB.saveProfessors(filename, al);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException > " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

UPDATE after comment:

```
public static void main(String[] aArgs) {
    TextDB txtDB = new TextDB();
    String filename = "professor.txt";
    try {
        //check if the file exist
        File oFile = new File(filename);
        if(!oFile.exist()) {
            oFile.mkdirs(); //optional
            oFile.createNewFile();
        }
        // read file containing Professor records.
        ArrayList al = TextDB.readProfessors(filename);
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            Professor prof = (Professor) al.get(i);
            System.out.println("Name " + prof.getName());
            System.out.println("Contact " + prof.getContact());
        }

        Professor p1 = new Professor("Joseph", "jos@ntu.edu.sg", 67909999);
        // al is an array list containing Professor objs
        al.add(p1);
        // write Professor record/s to file.
        TextDB.saveProfessors(filename, al);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException > " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: For the second portion right, let's say if the file not exist, is there any ways to create the file?

Answer (score 0):

Before attempting to read the file in your application, create it if it doesn't exist, either directly :

```
String filename = "professor.txt" ;
File file = new File(fileName);

if(!file.exists()){
  file.createNewFile();
}
```

Or by calling your `write` method.

```
String filename = "professor.txt" ;
File file = new File(fileName);

if(!file.exists()){
  TextDB.saveProfessors(filename, new ArrayList());
}
```

The [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File)) will create the file for you, even though nothing is written to it (like with this empty list).